# Connect to instagram with request

Tags: python, python-requests, request, instagram

i'm coding a new project to improve my python skills. It takes data of instagram's profils and treat them. Until now it worked, I could access to different pages. But i think  that by doing too much requests, the server has logged out me. I don't know how to connect with python requests so i'm blocked.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Here my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import os

def get_info_insta(username):

    url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{username}/'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'email': 'email',
        'pass' : 'password'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.post(url, data=headers)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")

    title = str(soup.find("meta",  property="og:description"))
    print(soup)
    title = title.split("-")[0]
    #title = title.split("=")[1]
    #title = title.split('"')[1]
    return title


title = get_info_insta('javascripthub')  #ewa.english   javascripthub



def treat_data(): 

    title = get_info_insta('ewa.english')  #ewa.english   javascripthub


    #on coupe pour avoir les différentes variables
    title_set = title.split(",")

    title_number = len(title.split(",")) #on compte en combien de fois coupé pour savoir si il y a un chiffre en millier
    pst = title_number - 1 #pour avoir dernier numéro liste

    if "Followers" in title_set[0]:
        title_followers = title_set[0].replace(" Followers", "") #garde juste nombre
    else:
        title_followers = f"{title_set[0]}{title_set[1]}".replace(" Followers", "")

    title_following = title_set[1].replace(" Following", "") #garde juste nombre


    if title_number >= 4: #si chiffre en millier:
        title_posts = f"{title_set[pst-1]}{title_set[pst]}".replace(" Posts", "")
    else: #sinon
        title_posts = title_set[2].replace(" Posts", "")




    print(title, ">", title_followers, ">", title_following, ">", title_posts)
```

Comment: it is called throttling. sites like instagram you need to be able to use timer to slow accessing it. next time use selenium or the like for scraping such sites.

Answer (score 0):

The instagram API limits the API requests per user, also called rate limiting. A user can make at most 200 API calls per hour. So if you have made up to 200 API calls in the hour, then you need to wait till the hour gets over and it will stop blocking you.

Comment: Ok, but i'm not using the API, i'm just using python requests directly on link.

Comment: Oh, ok. If you are not using the API you shouldn't use the api tag.

Comment: You're right i shoudn't ! But do you have a idea ?

Comment: No, idea! I think that the first comment on the question may help! On google, it shows - Bandwidth throttling is the intentional slowing or speeding of an internet service by an Internet service provider.